# swift how to convert date component in a double to get upload speed

Tags: swift, nsdatecomponents

I try to check the speed of upload by sending an image to a server via FTP, I know it is not very sharp, but I have no alternative. Issue number one is to test time, this code is always giving me 0 seconds maybe it is right maybe not, but the main issue id that I cannot even divide the size in mb of image by time in seconds, since time elapsed is expressed in dateComponent, how to do it?

using this code

```
func pushfileUpload() {
    print("uploading...")

    let startDate = NSDate()

    //*****************************************************************



    //find file in app bundle
    let imageChecked = findFileInBundle(nameWithNoEx: "image", extension: "jpg")
    //convert to Data
    let imageData = imageChecked.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
    //instanziate the class
    let ftpUploader = FTPUpload.init(baseUrl: Constants.kHostname, userName: Constants.kUsername, password: Constants.kPassword, directoryPath: Constants.kFolder)

    ftpUploader.send(data: imageData!, with: "image") { (result) in
        if result {
            print("result is \(result)")
        } else {
            print("no result")
        }
    }


    //*****************************************************************
    print("...uploaded")
    let endDate = NSDate()
    let difference = timeDifference(date1: startDate as Date, date2: endDate as Date)
//        print("Time difference is : \(difference)")


    //1 converto to string
    let differenceString = String(difference)
    //2 pick first 3 ints
    let array = differenceString.compactMap{Int(String($0))}
    //3 create new int
    let newInt = array[0...3]

    var newString = ""
    for i in newInt {
        newString.append(i.description)
    }
    var fromIntToString = Int(newString)

    fromIntToString = fromIntToString! * 1000

    let speed = 1500 / fromIntToString!
    print("speed: \(speed)")



}





func timeDifference(date1: Date, date2: Date) -> Int {

    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    var compos:Set<Calendar.Component> = Set<Calendar.Component>()
    //        compos.insert(.second)
    compos.insert(.nanosecond)
    let difference = calendar.dateComponents(compos, from: date1, to: date2)
    //        print("diff in seconds= \(difference.second!)") // difference in seconds
    print("diff in nanoseconds = \(difference.nanosecond!)") // difference in nanoseconds

    let newValue = difference.nanosecond!

    return newValue
}
```

//UPADTED code

```
func pushfileUpload() {
    print("uploading...")

    let startDate = Date()

    //*****************************************************************
    //find file in app bundle
    let imageChecked = findFileInBundle(nameWithNoEx: "image", extension: "jpg")
    //convert to Data
    let imageData = imageChecked.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
    //instanziate the class
    let ftpUploader = FTPUpload.init(baseUrl: Constants.kHostname, userName: Constants.kUsername, password: Constants.kPassword, directoryPath: Constants.kFolder)

    ftpUploader.send(data: imageData!, with: "image") { (result) in
        if result {
            print("result is \(result)")
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            //Your code to calculate elapsed time belongs here
            let endDate = Date()
            let elapsed = endDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate -
                startDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
            print("The download took \(elapsed) seconds.")
            print("speed is \(1500 / elapsed)")
            //-----------------------------------------------------
        } else {
            print("no result")
        }
    }}
```

prints on console

```
The download took 1.281269907951355 seconds.
speed is 1170.7135168720042
```

Comment: It's always 0 because you're calculating the time after the upload is started, not when it's ended. Move your code to the line that says `print("result is \(result)")`.

Comment: added code, now using nanoseconds, this way measure is good, moving the code did not solved the true issue, concert that result, now in nanosecond into something I can divide by image size

Comment: Why do you use `DateComponents`? Why not just comparing the two `Dates`? If you use Swft3+, avoid NSStuff when possible: `NSDate` => `Date`, `NSCalendar` => `Calendar`, etc.

Comment: How could I do it? I updated a bit the code, now I'm using ints for components , but Speed is always 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you need to move your code that calculates total time inside your closure:

```
func pushfileUpload() {
    print("uploading...")

    let startDate = Date()

    //*****************************************************************
    //find file in app bundle
    let imageChecked = findFileInBundle(nameWithNoEx: "image", extension: "jpg")
    //convert to Data
    let imageData = imageChecked.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
    //instanziate the class
    let ftpUploader = FTPUpload.init(baseUrl: Constants.kHostname, userName: Constants.kUsername, password: Constants.kPassword, directoryPath: Constants.kFolder)

    ftpUploader.send(data: imageData!, with: "image") { (result) in
        if result {
            print("result is \(result)")
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            //Your code to calculate elapsed time belongs here
            let endDate = Date()
            let elapsed = endDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - 
               startDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
            print("The download took \(elasped) seconds."
            //-----------------------------------------------------
        } else {
            print("no result")
        }
    }
```

...

As others have mentioned, there's no reason to deal with date components. The method timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate gives you a double precision count of seconds for a date, so it's easy to do math on dates to figure out the difference between them. You can evaluate the difference to as many decimal places as you want.

Comment: Why not simply `let elapsed = endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)`? Btw `let startDate = NSDate()` drop the NS prefix from date

Comment: Sure, I could have done it all in one shot, but when for the verbose approach for a forum post. I copied the OPs code, so that NS call snuck through.

Comment: your answer now allows to get time in seconds, but if I add the math of my code after yours , the speed is still 0, how could I calculate it? It seems to be logically right!

Comment: Did you put the code inside the completion handler as in my answer?

Comment: updated my question with your code, please check the updated part,So I can check your answer as right. I think it is right now . I had to remove the math, now since elapsed is a double I can divide i by the image size. now speed is measured, but is a very long number, may I reduce it? I cannot understand what it shows, bytes per second? how could I reduce it?

Comment: Your updated code uses a constant value of 1500 for the file size. If you want to calculate bytes/second, use `Double(imageData.count)/elapsed`. If you want to calculate k/second, use `Double(imageData.count)/elapsed/1024'